# Truffle "test" is passing only 1 it("") test instead of showing "all 3 tests passed"

Tags: truffle, truffle-test, truffle-deployment, test

---

### MyToken.sol

```
//// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.6.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";

contract MyToken is ERC20 {
    constructor(uint256 initialSupply) ERC20("StarDucks Capu-Token", "SCT") public {
        _mint(msg.sender, initialSupply);
        _setupDecimals(0);
    }
}
```

---

### MyToken.test.js

```
const Token = artifacts.require("MyToken");

var chai = require("chai");

const BN = web3.utils.BN;
const chaiBN = require('chai-BN')(BN);
chai.use(chaiBN);

var chaiAsPromised = require("chai-as-promised");
chai.use(chaiAsPromised);

const expect = chai.expect;

contract("Token Test", async accounts => {
const [ initialHolder, recipient, anotherAccount ] = accounts;

it("All tokens should be in my account", async() => {
    let instance = await Token.deployed();
    let totalSupply = await instance.totalSupply();
    expect(instance.balanceOf(initialHolder)).to.eventually.be.a.bignumber.equal(totalSupply);
})

if("I can send tokens from Account 1 to Account 2", async () => {
    const sendTokens = 1;
    let instance = await Token.deployed();
    let totalSupply = await instance.totalSupply();
    expect(instance.transfer(reciepient, sendTokens)).to.eventually.be.fulfilled;
    expect(instance.balanceOf(initialHolder)).to.eventually.be.a.bignumber.equal(totalSupply.sub(new BN(sendTokens)));
    expect(instance.balanceOf(recipient)).to.eventually.be.a.bignumber.equal(new BN(sendTokens));
})

if("It's not possible to send more tokens than account 1 has", async () => {
    let instance = await Token.deployed();
    let balanceOfAccount = await instance.balanceOf(initialHolder);

    expect(instance.transfer(recipient, new BN(balanceOfAccount+1))).to.eventually.be.rejected;
    expect(instance.balanceOf(initialHolder)).to.eventually.be.a.bignumber.equal(balanceOfAccount);
}); 

});
```

---

### test output:

[image]

Comment: Change `if` to `it` in that last two clauses. Note that this is a really low-quality question!

Comment: @goodvibration Thanks for answering. It worked!! I am sorry for this low-quality question, Next time I will make it more readable for sure.

Comment: It's not about readability, it's about your typo (replacing `it` with `if`).

Comment: @goodvibration I understood, I replaced it successfully. These problems are occurring only with JavaScript files while creating Smart Contract project, because I don't know JavaScript so sometimes unable to solve errors.